# My non-inverting amplifing circuit is always giving constant output values

Tags: voltage, operational-amplifier, amplifier, non-inverting

I need to amplify voltages from range of -5mV/5mV to voltages of range -5V/5V. So I used circuit from the image.[image: Amplifying circuit] [LF356N](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lf356.pdf)

I decided to check if it is working by connecting it to Arduino Uno to simulate signal and to power the amplifier. When checking the output voltage I found that it is 3.5V. After removing the signal, output voltage did not change, it was still 3.5V.

I am new to this kind of circuits and I cannot find the problem why it is not amplifying the signal but giving constant values. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your LF356 is not specified to operate with only a 5V supply. Not even close. Read the datasheet.

Comment: Also note that the LF356 has a typical 3mV input offset voltage. Your circuit has a DC gain of 1000, so that would mean that, even if the supply was OK, you would have 3V at the output even with the non-inverting input connected to GND, because you'd be amplifying the offset.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read the datasheet before choosing an op-amp.

You are violating the recommended supply voltage range

[image]

and the input common-mode voltage range

[image]